# ReactiveSwift. Zipping an array of signal producers

Tags: reactive-swift

I have an array of signal producers that fetch similar objects from the backend like [SignalProducer`<`Object, NSError`>`].
How can I zip them to have array of their results [Object] every time they all are finished?
I know there zip operators with predefined number of producers, but it is not a case, as the number of requests to send is known only in runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SignalProducer` has a static `zip` function that accepts a sequence of producers.](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/1.1.3/Sources/SignalProducer.swift#L1660)

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. But it gives a compile error, that this function still wants second argument.<br>
var producers: [SignalProducer<StyledBusinessObjects, NSError>] = []<br>
...<br>
return SignalProducer.zip(producers)

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a type inference ambiguity. Try `SignalProducer<StyledBusinessObjects, NSError>.zip(producers)`

Comment: No, it was my fault. Had the wrong result type from the function. Thank you!